# how to fire an event-triggering function from an event handler without creating an infinite loop?

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, jquery-mobile

I'm trying to fire my function *panelTrans* from within this event binding:

```
$(document).on( "pagebeforechange", function( e, data ) {           
    console.log("fired");
    // cond
    if ( data.options.pageContainer != $.mobile.pageContainer ) {

       if ( self.options.$infinity != "block" )  {
           // set a blocker to avoid infinite loop
           self.options.$infinity = "block"

           // stop JQM
           e.preventDefault();      
           e.stopPropagation();

           // fire panel transition
           self.panelTrans(e, data);
           }
      }  
  });
```

The problem is, the panelTrans function fires a changePage, which triggers another pagebeforechange event, so I'm creating an inifinte loop. I'm trying to block this with the inifite loop option. However, this seems to not block "fast" enough, beause I'm still getting several "iterations/loops" = console is logging 3-5 "fired". If I move the preventDefault outside of the if-statements, it prevents everything, which also does not work.

**Question:**
Is there a better way to handle this? I need to intercept the changePage before Jquery Mobile inits it's transition to overwrite the changePage options and fire my a modified changePage for Jquery Mobile to execute.

Thanks for help!

Comment: Why do you fire the `changePage` event ? if you complete execution of your function (ie changing options) then the event will be fired anyway ?

Comment: @ManseUK: I tried this in the beginning, but by the time panelTrans is through options modifying, the JQM pagechange already fired, so I need to fire a new one.

Answer (score 0):

What is `self` and what does `panelTrans` do?

Of course you may get more than one "fired" loggings, because it is not inside the conditionals. Especially when the loop is blocked, it still will log the new event.

Have you tried logging the execution of `panelTrans()` instead?

Comment: sorry, cut out too much code. self = this, so I'm calling plugin functions using self.pluginFunction1, self.pluginFunction2... PanelTrans modifies the default Jquery Mobile changePage options (plus other things) and ends up firing a new changePage. Good pointer with the execution of panelTrans, I will give that a try.

Answer (score 0):

You should check the type on `data.toPage` and only cancel the event when toPage is a string.

The call to `$.mobile.changePage()` should be a page object.

Here's an example I did for another question. http://jsfiddle.net/kiliman/zMnUM/

```
$(document).bind('pagebeforechange', function(e, data) {
    var to = data.toPage;

    if (typeof to  === 'string') {
        var u = $.mobile.path.parseUrl(to);
        to = u.hash || '#' + u.pathname;

        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();

        // call $.mobileChangePage() here,
        // make sure it's a page object like $('#page')

    }
});
```